# Magento - Inject custom module on product info page

Tags: templates, magento, block

I've searched on web for how to add "block" with my template on the product page. I build my custom module that displays some sort of information and I would like to show that, let's say under the long description of my product.

I've been trying to format the xml layout of my module but without luck.

After some search I've found this: [Programatically create Magento blocks and inject them into layout](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programatically-create-magento-blocks-and-inject-them-into-layout/) which I can not make it work for me. But it is probably because I've missed something.

My module is structured like this:

CODE: app/code/local/deveti/Countrypurchase

DESIGN: app/design/frontend/default/default/template/Countrypurchase/index.phtml

LAYOUT: app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/countrypurchase.xml

I know the correct way is to edit main layout file, manually add a block, but I'd like to do that on the fly.

EDIT: this works!

So I would do in my module layout xml countrypurchase.xml something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/template" name="product.countrypurchase" as="countrypurchase" template="countrypurchase/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>    
</layout>
```

And I've added a call to catalog/product/view.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('countrypurchase'); ?>
```

And it works ;)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I assume your cache is disabled and cleared?

Comment: Yes it is. I always test this things with cache disabled and cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the product view page is that it's output is mainly controlled by the PHP code in the template `catalog/product/view.phtml`. Magento doesn't offer much extensibility points out of the box. You could add it to the `content` block but that would put your custom content either completely at the top or completely at the bottom.

I think you are required to modify the template and add PHP code to render your custom block at the position you want, like:

```
<?php
    echo $this->getChildHtml('product.countrypurchase');
?>
```

With this in place you can either add your block with the name `product.countrypurchase` via the XML layout or programmatically.

Comment: I've added my code to the question if you can take a look. Thank you!

Comment: It worked. I'll edit the code in my question if anyone else needs this.